# Upwards vs up to

Tags: phrases

I'm wondering what the difference between upwards and up to is. For example, "This tree can grow upwards of 10 ft tall" vs "This tree can grow up to 10 ft tall". To me they seem to say the same thing, but co-authors are implying that there is a difference. Is "up to" considered more definitive and "upwards" a softer boundary?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Up to ten feet tall* means that the tallest tree of that type/species is ten feet high. *Upwards of ten feet tall* implies that the tree typically grows to ten feet, but some or many examples may be taller than that.

Answer (score 3):

"This tree can grow upwards of 10 ft tall" implies that the tree will be least 10ft and could be taller.

"This tree can grow up to 10 ft tall" implies that the maximum the tree can grow to is 10ft but could be less.

To answer the second part of the question: neither phrase is particularly definitive.